# Do pilots eat the same food as passengers?

Tags: airline-operations

I imagine it might be hard to find a time when pilots can eat, but when they do, what do they eat?

Comment: Three questions, three duplicates. Can I suggest that you explore the capabilities of the search bar at the top of the page before posting again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, commercial pilots eat the same meals that the passengers do. They may have extra snacks and such that the passengers don't, but that's it.

It's actually quite easy to find time to eat, since the majority of the actual control manipulation is handled by the autopilot. If the autopilot isn't available for whatever reason, one person can fly while the other eats.

Fun fact: Most airlines have a policy that the pilots must eat different meals, so that if there was a bad batch of chicken that gave everyone who ate it food poisoning, then the pilot that had the fish can still fly and land the plane.

Comment: Every now and then it actually happens that a pilot gets sick from food, so the practise of eating different meals is a really good one.

Comment: You will find more and more pilots and flight crew packing their own meals. Especially at the regional level. Younger pilots and health-minded pilots are opting for healthier choices than airline or airport food. Not a bad idea considering your health **is** your livelihood in a manner of speaking.

Comment: One possible source for the different meals policy is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_into_Danger and its more recent parody *Airplane!*